# View executed commands in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a eclipse based product. Basically it's a plugin built over eclipse which adds multiple functionalities, buttons, menu entries, a new interface and other stuff. I would like to automate some daily tasks but I don't know what commands are running behind the scenes. Is there a log with the running commands or something similar? 
 I don't have acces to the source code neither can contact the product owners.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple log of commands.

You can enable tracing for a lot of different components of Eclipse but the trace output generally assumes you know a lot about Eclipse internals.

Recent releases of Eclipse have a preference page to enable tracing in 'General > Tracing'. This is described in the Eclipse help [here](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-tracing_preference_page.htm).

You can also enable tracing using command line options as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is way more complex than I expected. I expected a feature which if activated will show in console the command used when I press button1 and then I could have put that command in a batch and tada.

Comment: Note that Eclipse doesn't support any kind of batch file or command line interface.

Comment: I didn't mean to execute something inside the eclipse environment, I'm not sure if I can explain that right. Assuming that you have eclipse with the button `Compile`, what I am trying to achieve, instead of opening eclipse, clicking on the button `Compile`, is to create a batch file which will have a command call, something like `eclipse.exe -do=Compile` and the actions to be done automatically